# Error creating custom templates visual studio 2012

Tags: debugging, templates, visual-studio-2012

I am creating custom templates in visual studio by implementing the IWizard based on the msdn link.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsx/archive/2014/06/10/creating-a-vsix-deployable-project-or-item-template-with-custom-wizard-support.aspx

I have below code in .vstemplate -

```
<WizardExtension>
    <Assembly>MSDNVSIXProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=f19bee03b9021a52</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>MSDNVSIXProject.Template</FullClassName>
    </WizardExtension>
```

I need to debug the newly created class which is implementing the IWizard. When I choose the template while creating the project I get the error

> Error: this template attenmpted to load component assembly
>   'MyAssembly, Version 1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken =xxxxx'.
>   For more information on this problem and how to enable this template,
>   please see documentation on Customizing Project Templates.

I ran the command devenv /installvstemplates as well.

Any suggestions on how I can debug this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the assembly into the GAC after signing it solved the problem.
There is an even better way to create templates programatically and not requiring it to be installed in the GAC. Please find the post below.

http://oncoding.blogspot.com/2012/04/visual-studio-template-wizards-without.html